Completing next rows by other columns in Power BI
I need to create a new column D in Power BI. If there is a value in C, keep it (such as the first row in the attached table) equal to 110 (so D1=C1), if not (C=Null or Blank), the value in the second row in the D column is D2=D1(previous day) + B2 (current day) - A2(current day) and repeat it for all next rows in column D, for example, as there is no any value in row C3 it can be D3=D2-A3+B3. I need to complete all rows in D using the above method.
I was wondering if anyone could help me!
Relavant Table
I need to complete all rows in column D as the above method.
I was wondering if anyone could help me!

Could you update the question to include some of the formulae that you have tried for column D and some details of how they did not meet your needs?

Try this calculated column:
D = 
VAR C = MAX('Table'[C])
VAR thisRow = 'Table'[Row]

VAR A = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[A])
        ,FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Row] <= thisRow
        && 'Table'[Row] <> 1)
)
VAR B = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[B])
        ,FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Row] <= thisRow
        && 'Table'[Row] <> 1)
)

RETURN IF('Table'[Row]=1, C, C + B - A)

Example Output:


Hi, thanks a lot for your time. it works for D1 and D2 but for D3 it must be D2-A3+B3 and D4=D3-A3+B3 and so on.

Sorry for the inconvenience, I have fixed my answer above.
